# Workbench - postgresql how to refresh table

Tags: postgresql

I get postgresql database at my work, it was managed by person whos not work anymore there, there is no documentation and I have very little experience with postgresql.

The thing is that one table is no longer updated, my question is how can I find in workbench what code actually updates the table. I was googling workbench documentation and also trying to find it in this program but with no luck.

Comment: A table has no way of knowing what code was running to generate the DML statements that modified the table. Your best bet is to search your codebase for the table name.

Comment: Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you manage to connect to Postgres with **MySQL** Workbench?

Comment: The database is typically updated from code _outside_ of the database. You should first look into your application code that works with the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about "workbench" but it doesn't seem as if this tool is going to help you much in your investigation.

1. As suggested by @AdamKG, scan your codebase.
2. If you have DB logs from when the table used to get updated, then you *might* be able to find clues from there: User IP, application name, DB user name, SQL, etc. This depends heavily on your DB logging parameters. And your logs retention policy, of course...